# VB.net Cell Value Return DBNull

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dbnull

I have an DataGridView with custom DataTable (not SQL database). where my coding like this

```
Sub Tabel()
        Tabel1 = New DataTable

        With Tabel1
            .Columns.Add("kodebarang")
            .Columns.Add("namabarang")
            .Columns.Add("satuan")
            .Columns.Add("harga", GetType(Double))
            .Columns.Add("jumlah", GetType(Integer))
            .Columns.Add("hargatotal", GetType(Double))
        End With

        DataGridView1.DataSource = Tabel1

        With DataGridView1
            .Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
            .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Item Name"
            .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Unit"
            .Columns(3).HeaderText = "Unit Price"
            .Columns(4).HeaderText = "Qty"
            .Columns(5).HeaderText = "Total Price"

            .Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "###,###,###"
            .Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "###,###,###"

            .Columns(1).ReadOnly = True
            .Columns(2).ReadOnly = True
            .Columns(3).ReadOnly = True
            .Columns(5).ReadOnly = True

            .Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
            .Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray

            .Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
            .Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            .Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight

            .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightBlue

            .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(4).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(5).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

            .Columns(1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        End With

        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(i).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
        Next i
    End Sub
```

and I use CellEndEdit to change datagrid cell value.

```
Private Sub DataGridView_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        celWasEndEdit = DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)

        txtNamaBarang.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
            Call Connect()

            Sql = "SELECT * FROM databarang WHERE kodebarang='" & DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value & "'"
            Cmd = New OdbcCommand(Sql, Con)
            Read = Cmd.ExecuteReader

            While Read.Read()
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = Read("namabarang")
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = Read("satuan")
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = Read("hargapartai")
            End While
        ElseIf e.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
            Dim Quantity As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Value
            Dim UnitPrice As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value

            Dim TotalPrice As Integer = Quantity * UnitPrice
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Value = TotalPrice
        End If
    End Sub
```

[DataGridView Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIaol.png)

but i got error when I change Column 4 (Qty) Value. **Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid.**, but if change my code to

```
ElseIf e.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")
        End If
```

I can get the Column 3 Value in MsgBox.

Comment: In order to use `CellEndEdit` you must first use `CellBeginEdit` with this scenario of yours. Also, if you want to format the DataGridView, use `CellFormatting`

Comment: I see. So the `e.ColumnIndex = 4` should be inside `CellBeginEdit` ?

Comment: No, not what I meant.

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway ?

Comment: So i have 6 Column in total, where:

`Column 0 = ID Number,
Column 1 = Item Name,
Column 2 = Unit,
Column 3 = Unit Price,
Column 4 = Quantity,
Column 5 = Total Price.`

What i need to do is Calculate `Total Price` Where if user Enter number ini `Column 4`, the `Column 5` Value will show the result of `Column 3 * Column 4`. I add it on `CellEndEdit`, because i thought the command will be generate when it's EndEdit the cell

Comment: And you are wanting to do so, while the DataGridView is bound to the Database ?!

Comment: Bound to DataTable, not Database. So the datagrid just keep the data that i input until i execute it to database. So, i can add, edit, or delete it until the data was ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do any of that if your DataGridView is bound to a DataTable; just set an expression on the total column that calculates the multiple of the other two columns:

```
    Tabel1 = New DataTable

    With Tabel1
        .Columns.Add("kodebarang")
        .Columns.Add("namabarang")
        .Columns.Add("satuan")
        .Columns.Add("harga", GetType(Double))
        .Columns.Add("jumlah", GetType(Integer))
        Dim dc = .Columns.Add("hargatotal", GetType(Double))   ''changed line
        dc.Expression = "[harga] * [jumlah]"                   ''new line
    End With

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Tabel1
```

On a related note, you shouldn't be accessing data via the datagridview; data lives in the datatable and should be accessed from there, not via the control that is displaying it

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the answer and the advice. really apreciate it.

Comment: Is it possible to get the sum of hargatotal to label.text? I've been using CellValueChanged but it only works after i add 2 row on datagridview and the label only sum first row value. not include row 2 hargatotal value. If I add row no. 3 it will sum hargatotal Row 1 and Row 2

Comment: Just bind the label text to that column of the datatable. Or if you mean that the label is to show the sum of all rows add another column to the datatable, set it's .Expression property to `SUM([hargatotal])` or `SUM([harga] * [jumlah])` and then bind the label to that new column. You keep thinking about data in terms of the UI controls; you should be thinking about it in terms of the datatable the data lives in.

Comment: I already bind it to label but it only works if i add more than 1 column. If row 1 added, the label not show the sum but if i add row 2 it will sum the HargaTotal column but only HargaTotal Row 1..

If 1 Row added it Will not Sum HargaTotal
If 2 Row added it will only sum Row 1 HargaTotal
If 3 Row Added it will only sum Row 1 + Row 2 HargaTotal

Comment: I tried this code `CellValueChanged`

`Dim sum As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DataTabel.Compute("SUM(HargaTotal)", String.Empty))
lblGrandTotal.Text = sum`

Comment: I have a doubt that it was done like I say: make a new column, set its expression to be a sum, bind a label to it. If you did it with CellValueChanged, that is not databinding. If you did it with Compute, that is not an Expression property